# Is the depth buffer size the same as the view port size?

Tags: opengl, depth-buffer

If I perform

```
#define SCREEN_SIZE 512
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
glViewport(0, 0, SCREEN_SIZE, SCREEN_SIZE);
```

Does this make my depth buffer size SCREEN_SIZE x SCREEN_SIZE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does this make my depth buffer size SCREEN_SIZE x SCREEN_SIZE?

No. The depth buffer is part of the window frame buffer. Usually such a window framebuffer consists of

- front color plane
- back color plane
- depth buffer
- stencil buffer

All these planes have the same size, namely the size of the window on which the OpenGL context has been created on. The viewport just defines the subset of the window that will be mapped the [-1, 1] range of *normalized device coordinates*, i.e. it *selects* a part of the framebuffer which will be used as projection target. The viewport doesn't even need to clip things "outside" the viewport range. If you need this, you must combine it with a *scissor test*.

Comment: I guess, the next natural question is: how do I set my depth buffer size? I want to use the depth buffer for computation of surface overlapping from a view point.

Comment: Just use a frame buffer object of the desired size.

Comment: I have had a lot of problem getting a good example of using FBO with QtOpenGL which allows me to do this. Perhaps, you have a link that I can peruse?